# Twitter Bootstrap Modal: make width and height the same size as user's max resolution

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you click the "Launch demo modal" button:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

I want that modal to be the same width and height as the user's resolution. In other words, the max size that the user's monitor supports. I also want the modal to be situated in the top left of the document.

I can manually set the width and height properties like so:

```
.modal {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 1335px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

But these are specific to my resolution. How can it be set in a way that it will apply to each user's unique resolution?

Also the top: 0 and left: 0 rules don't seem to be working. The modal shows cut off at the top and isn't all the way to the left either.

### EDIT

Silly me, the bootstrap css had some default negative margin on the modal class. This works:

```
.modal {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Height will be set using jquery to get view port height and setting that as an inline style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure CSS

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-body {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 0;
}
```

Works for me (tested in Chrome, FF and Opera) the opening effect remains ..